# What are the arguments for api.query.childBounties.childBounties

Tags: polkadot, frame

In the documentation [api.query.childBounties.childBounties](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#childbountiesu32-u32-optionpalletchildbountieschildbounty) takes two u32 arguments:
[image]

But it is not clear what are those arguments. Can someone tell me how to map polkadot js api to substrate rust code so these lookups can be checked.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [Rust source](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ee3eb8f2448cc1bb978c5d1564febd351c128bb0/frame/child-bounties/src/lib.rs#L197-L204) for the double map.

It is a link from the parent id to the child id.